# How to define filtered array in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics

I have an array with two possible values. It might include an expected object, or an object which defines an error. The data could look something like this:

```json
// mixedData
[
    { item1: "value", item2: "value2" },
    { error: true, description: "no value found" },
];
```

I made two types for this array. One for a valid object and one for the error object. I then defined my array like this:

```js
const myArray: Array<IValid | IError> = [] // fetched from api
```

Next I want to remove every object with an error field from the array, leaving me with `IValid` objects only:

```js
const filteredData: IValid[] = mixedData.filter(
    (obj: IValid | IError) => !obj.hasOwnProperty("error")
);
```

This works but TypeScript does not really like this because it still thinks an item could be of `IError`:

```
Error: Type '(IValid| IError)[]' is not assignable to type 'IValid[]'.
```

How do I make TypeScript happy here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use typeguard as a `filter` predicate:

```js
type IValid = { item1: string, item2: string }

type IError = { error: boolean, description: string }

type All = IValid | IError

const data: All[] = [
    { item1: 'value', item2: 'value2' },
    { error: true, description: 'no value found' }
]

const myArray: Array<IValid | IError> = [] // fetched from api

const hasProperty = <Obj, Prop extends string>(obj: Obj, prop: Prop)
    : obj is Obj & Record<Prop, unknown> =>
    Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop);

const filteredData = data.filter((obj): obj is IValid /** here is the trick */ => !hasProperty(obj, 'error')); // IValid[]
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgagQwDYEsAmUC8UDeUXAQC2AjAFxQDOwATigHYDmANPoUQEwXV1NQC%20AWABQI0JFgBRGjQD2NLLigQZ8igCNZspBAT1WaCJQDGdMMBSz63Wg0YCRY8NACCSJIvjJ0UAD5TVGkdhYytqKDQEYAQKNyQAbQBdRXiRKHSlAmJyKAByADdkAFcIXNYszgoC4ogOXIFmNIy8FTkaCloSgyNTFHNLazz6WShCpBKoADNZIvo0eqFhRODQ%20nCiEBcZBBBY7ZAAHi9UDH8YaTaAPhTkgHpbqYhgYwALCAxJuSIoBDAUFbCwCgLwQlAACnJIDRQIoDgB5dQAK1YENkYGUAA9CHNKFRbExLgAKWRIigI5FQMCQiiosAASia6QoJMR%20Fx5KgADIoAAlCChGhoA601izADWwwA7vRrphLoyoOT%20cAAHRU2TADXOFUgyhw6W0lSgFXGZBIYlI1jq%20kAbgBayBkxQSEINHeABEoghFJFoiqnS6VISLYi6cykWzYIgTlhrgBCXWG6EgEOsXKteS5Ol0m1Qe5R7xoJLBIA)

`Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call` is much safer than `obj.hasOwnProperty`, see [eslint rule](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-prototype-builtins)

Answer (score 2):

Just cast to validData[].

```
const filteredData: validData[] = mixedData.filter((obj: IValid | IError) => !obj.hasOwnProperty('error')) as validData[];
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple example with `Type Guards`

```js
interface IValid { item1: string; item2: string };
interface IError { error: boolean; description: string };

const data: Array<IValid | IError> = [
    { item1: "value", item2: "value2" },
    { error: true, description: "no value found" },
];

function isValid(obj: IValid | IError): obj is IValid {
    return (obj as IError).error === undefined;
}

const filteredValidData = data.filter(isValid);
console.log(filteredValidData);
// [ { item1: "value", item2: "value2" } ]
```

Other examples from [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#user-defined-type-guard-functions)